Duplicate Entries in Salesforce Login History Report
I’ve noticed that the 'Login History' object in Salesforce shows multiple successful logins for the same time period for several users, resulting in duplicate records in my reports. I’ve come across some known issues related to this behavior on Salesforce's side.
Is there a way to remove these duplicates from my reports, or are there alternative solutions to handle this issue effectively? Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

As per the article,

There are different scenarios in which a user's login history may show
seemingly duplicate records:

This may occur if a user has clicked the Login button multiple times before actually being logged in.
This behavior may occur if your organization utilizes any connected apps. These apps also access the User's login details and
create a record in the user's login history.
This also occurs if the system is idle for an extended time period, and is then unlocked.

This is expected behavior of the
'Login History' report and data displayed in related list of User's
Login History.


Hi Tushar,
I understand that the current behavior is expected, but I’m looking for a solution to remove duplicate records from the report. Is there a way to achieve this through Apex code or any other way some external tool/ some package from app exchanger? I want to  generate a CSV file without duplicates and send it via email. Thanks
